# Can three bodies be collinear all the time under the influence of gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, three-body-problem

if a spacecraft is set into orbit around a binary star system such that it is collinear with the two stars. if the distance of the spacecraft from each of the stars is $R$ and $r$ then what will be the ratio of the masses of the stars? is this a stable one?

Answer (score 1):

In general this situation expressed in the title is true of arrangements with a light body in the first, second or third [Lagrange point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) associated with a pair of orbiting massive bodies.

Such arrangements are, however, unstable and won't persist in real life without some kind of station-keeping.

Comment: My comment deleted, (and forgotten), but now Lagrange points won't be. Thanks

Comment: So basically L1 and L2 .